# Java varargs allocates array objects?

Tags: java, variadic-functions

Wow! I have just realized that varargs methods in Java cause an array to be allocated when they are called. Not sure why I would expect anything different, but should there perhaps be some kind of pooling for the arrays? At least for the initial 0 to 8 sizes? Is there any workaround in Java to use varargs without causing an array allocation for every call?

EDIT: Please understand that leaking memory **to the GC** is just an unwanted overhead/latency. It is *NOT* a bug like some comments implied. Just because Java has GC does not mean you can create tons of garbage at will.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *leaking memory*? Are you saying that the arrays allocated for varargs are never being freed during the lifetime of the application?

Comment: Please post some example code that demonstrates this issue that millions of developers haven't seemed to have noticed in the last 15 years.

Comment: I was clear: leaking memory to the GC. This is not a bug. Again: leaking memory "TO THE GC", which means it creates an overhead to the GC, in other words, triggers the GC if called too many times due to garbage being created. It is funny that you thought I was saying varargs had a bug. I can post some code to show it tomorrow. I just thought the arrays could be internally pooled or something.

Comment: You mean, like, leaking water into a drainpipe?

Comment: People are confused because you are using “memory leak” incorrectly. I edited your question to use clearer terms, but I think you accidentally overwrote my edit when you made yours.

Comment: @Stuart - Agreed. I think the correct term would be "overhead" or something similar, rather than "leak".

Comment: Wow! It looks like this question might get leaked to the GC.

Comment: -1 - this behaviour is NOT a memory leak according to the normally accepted use of this term.

Comment: Worth reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak

Comment: The overhead is insignificant. Varargs is just a bit flag for the method (similar for `public` or `synchronized`). The real signature is some sort of array. Unless you were unaware varargs is synthetic sugar, just as "for in",

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the example of `EnumSet`. the vararg method

```
of(E first, E... rest)
```

is overloaded with

```
of(E e1, E e2) 
of(E e1, E e2, E e3) 
of(E e1, E e2, E e3, E e4) 
of(E e1, E e2, E e3, E e4, E e5)
```

to avoid the vararg array creation if args are 5 or less. (EnumSet probably goes too far here)

I don't think this is really a GC concern. The array created is dereferenced very quickly, such die-young garbage should have almost no impact to GC.

However, instantiating an array is a relatively expensive operation; since EnumSet.add() is very fast, the overhead of array creation can be quite noticeable; they probably did some benchmark, and decided it's worthwhile to optimized with overloading for up to 5 args.

Comment: So having a bunch of methods to avoid the varargs is the workaround? That's fine but it pollutes your interface with those repeated methods. Maybe I will extend a dummy interface with these variations, just not to pollute the main one? Any other workaround? Probably not...

Comment: don't bother in most cases. but suppose you have a method like `int sum(int... args)`, the overhead of vararg can be relatively too big; since callers usually call it with only few args, overload the vararg version with methods of fixed args can be very beneficial.

Comment: @irreputable, calling w/ just a few parameters should result in escape analysis (provided it's common enough) and inline.

Comment: @bestsss experiment shows that's not the case, JVM isn't that smart yet. and inlining depends on the complexity of the caller method body, the API designer may not want to be subject to that.

Comment: @irreputable, EA is known to be very limited and studies (IBM ones) show that it doesn't yield any significant effect in real-world applications, outside the microbenchmark tests (where it rocks). C2 (server) compiler tends to inline quite large methods but at least it's very likely to unroll the loop (if matters). As for JVM being smart, it just takes some popular benchmark to use varargs (and cause any bottleneck) to be trained to do EA on varargs.

Comment: @bestsss well we want to know what VM does, today; not what it could. Any evidence VM can EA and unroll this little case? `int[] arr = new int[M]; for(int j=0; j<M; j++)arr[j]=j; for(int j=0; j<M; j++)sum+= arr[j];`

Comment: @irreputable, loop unrolled (+prefetch) for sure and range check eliminated too, better be j<arr.length, though. C2 is very keen on loop unrolling. about EA - not sure (I can check the C2 source but not tonight). I run the servers w/ EA disabled, though. Simple sum `for(int i=0;i<M;i++) sum+=i` is optimized away. If the EA kicks in, the code should run in constant time.

Comment: @bestsss forget the `new int[M]` part; the rest runs O(M). so I don't see evidence of optimization.

Comment: I overloading varargs up to 16 objects. You can see the result here: http://mentalog.soliveirajr.com. A Java library that allocates ZERO memory when logging to disk.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that in modern JVMs, allocating short-lived objects is usually pretty cheap. In most cases it's just not worth worrying about.

The VM *could* try to use some sort of cache, but I suspect that the complexity of doing so correctly would outweigh any benefit, and would probably end up allocating more objects too.

---

If you *really* want to avoid creating varargs arrays in a tight loop, there's nothing stopping you from creating your own array and passing it in directly, like so:

```
void twiddle(String... args) { ... }

void twiddleAllData() {
    String[] args = new String[2];

    for (Data d : getData()) {
        args[0] = d.getFirst();
        args[1] = d.getSecond();
        twiddle(args);
    }
}
```

Note that in this example, all of the calls to `twiddle` must pass exactly 2 arguments, because that's the size of the shared array that was created.

Comment: just a comment on the cache, it's more like to be EA (escape analyzed) than any cache to be used and the entire code to be loop-unrolled/inlined.